# How to execute if condition inside option tag in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, selectoption

I wanted to display a different text for a specific set of result from the records.
I tried the following code but it just displays the condition as it is.
Is this even possible inside the option tag?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.selectableRecords}" var="opts">
            <option value="{!opts.Id}"> Lot: {!opts.Lot_Number__c}, Unit: {!opts.Unit_Number__c} - 
                {!opts.Lot_Owner_Name__r.Name} 
                {!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'OC Member' ? '' : 
                opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Chairperson' ? '(Chair)' : 
                opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Committee Member' ? '(CM)' : 
                opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Committee Secretary' ? '(CS)' : 
                '' }</option>
        </aura:iteration>
```

[image]

Comment: Please check `<aura:if>` component, that might be helpful here.  Also, if there are lot of conditions, it would be better for you to perform it in the controller (js) and then iterate over the filtered list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `<aura:if>` - here are 2 possibilities:

**without else:**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.selectableRecords}" var="opts">
    <option value="{!opts.Id}"> 
        Lot: {!opts.Lot_Number__c}, Unit: {!opts.Unit_Number__c} - {!opts.Lot_Owner_Name__r.Name} 
        <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'OC Member'}"></aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Chairperson'}">(Chair)</aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Committee Member'}">(CM)</aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Committee Secretary'}">(CS)</aura:if>
    </option>
</aura:iteration>
```

**with else:**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.selectableRecords}" var="opts">
    <option value="{!opts.Id}"> 
        Lot: {!opts.Lot_Number__c}, Unit: {!opts.Unit_Number__c} - {!opts.Lot_Owner_Name__r.Name} 
        <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'OC Member'}">

            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Chairperson'}">
                    (Chair)
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Committee Member'}">
                            (CM)
                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!opts.OC_Member_Types__c == 'Committee Secretary'}">
                                    (CS)
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    </aura:set>
                                </aura:if>
                            </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </option>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Thank you Itai Shmida! What I ended up doing though is processing the list once I received it from server and Iterating that. But this looks better!